# How to handle SPLIT function in HIVE with different delimiters occurs on records

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have following problem in SPLIT function on HIVE.
my sample records are below:

chips/RAM

Software-Chip

Device & GPS

Chip  Vector

I want to split it and take the first element. For example,
select SPLIT('chips/RAM', '[/]') [1];
Results  **RAM**

How can i write split function if my delimiters are different . PLease help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The splitter in the Hive `split()` function is a regular expression.  You can try:

```
split(col, '[-/& ]')
```

Comment: it would be great if you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691921/how-to-write-recursive-cte-or-equivalent-to-accomplish-to-get-employee-and-manag